# Why browser download every php file from my server?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have some problems with my Ubuntu-Apache-Php environment!
I'm building my local development environment!Now,I have installed apache2,php7.0 and mysql 5.5 on Ubuntu.I can visit Apache's default Welcome page(a html page ) normally,also,after I enter `php -V` command ,I can see my Php7 version info.
After all,I build a php file (info.php)to test php-with-apache,the content of this file is below,the position of the file is '/var/www/html/info.php':
`<?php
  phpinfo();
   ?>`

If everything is corret,I would see php info when I visit `http://servrtIP/info.php`,but unfortunately,my browser download the file(info.php) directly.
Which is wrong?

Comment: You need to configure apache to process php files

Comment: PHP is not correctly configured on your server